# Why won't ruby-mcrypt accept an array as a key?

Tags: ruby, encryption

Hello I am having trouble encrypting using an array as the key and the value with the [ruby-mcrypt gem](https://github.com/kingpong/ruby-mcrypt). The gem lets me use an array for the key fine, `cipher = Mcrypt.new("rijndael-256", :ecb, secret)` works. But it will give me an error when I try to encrypt. I've tried many things but no luck. Does anyone know if Mcrypt just doesn't like encrypting with an array?

```
require 'mcrypt'

def encrypt(plain, secret)
  cipher = Mcrypt.new("rijndael-256", :ecb, secret)
  cipher.padding = :zeros

  encrypted = cipher.encrypt(plain)
  p encrypted
  encrypted.unpack("H*").first.to_s.upcase
end

array_to_encrypt = [16, 0, 0, 0, 50, 48, 49, 55, 47, 48, 50, 47, 48, 55, 32, 50, 50, 58, 52, 54, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
key_array = [65, 66, 67, 68, 49, 50, 51, 52, 70, 71, 72, 73, 53, 54, 55, 56]

result = encrypt(array_to_encrypt, key_array)
p "RESULT IS #{result}"
```

The output is as follows:

```
Mcrypt::RuntimeError: Could not initialize mcrypt: Key length is not legal.
```

I traced this error to [here](https://github.com/kingpong/ruby-mcrypt/blob/master/ext/mcrypt_wrapper.c#L150) in the `ruby-mcrypt` gem but don't understand it enough to figure out why I am getting the error message. Any help or insights would be amazing. Thanks!

Comment: Try `key_array.map(&:to_s)`? `key_array.map(&:size).inject(:+) => 128` whereas `key_array.map(&:to_s).map(&:size).inject(:+) => 32`.  If Mcrypt is not changing the ints to strings it may be giving it a 128byte / 1024bit key instead of 32byte / 256bit

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I am still getting the same error. I was hoping that would work cause that makes sense.

Comment: Try doubling the length of the array [65, 66, 67, 68, 49, 50, 51, 52, 70, 71, 72, 73, 53, 54, 55, 56, 65, 66, 67, 68, 49, 50, 51, 52, 70, 71, 72, 73, 53, 54, 55, 56]`.  That would match up with [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36826445/rijndael-key-size-in-c-sharp) where their hex array is twice as long for a 256 rijndael.

Comment: Judging by the fact that [the `key` accessor returns a `String`](https://rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-mcrypt/Mcrypt:key) and reading [between the lines of the documentation for `key=`](https://rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-mcrypt/Mcrypt:key=), I would guess that the key needs to be a `String` in `Encoding::BINARY` encoding.

Comment: @Tom I did try that and still got the same error

Comment: @JörgWMittag I suspect you are correct about that. That was what I was thinking. Just wanted to see if anyone else could verify this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library doesn't support arrays. You'll need to use Strings instead:

```
def binary(byte_array)
  byte_array.pack('C*')
end

array_to_encrypt = [16, 0, 0, 0, 50, 48, 49, 55, 47, 48, 50, 47, 48, 55, 32, 50, 50, 58, 52, 54, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
key_array = [65, 66, 67, 68, 49, 50, 51, 52, 70, 71, 72, 73, 53, 54, 55, 56]

result = encrypt(binary(array_to_encrypt), binary(key_array))
p "RESULT IS #{result}"
```